# unable to send array to listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview, intellij-idea

I am trying to get a json list of menu items from a server, parse it, and display it in a fragment view. The full code is here: http://pastebin.com/8UEgcyfa

Before the code for getting the json and parsing was added, the app was simply displaying a list of hard-coded menu items from a string resource as such:

```
String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

// Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_viewdishes, R.id.label, adobe_products));
```

This was correctly working. While trying to actually print the menu items received after parsing, i did this in the onPostExecute method (please see full code), where menuNameArray, (i think) correctly holds an array of menu items i actually need to display on ListView:

```
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_viewdishes, R.id.label, adobe_products));
```

IntelliJ IDEA throws an error at this point: `Cannot resolve method setListAdapter` . I thought that its actually ViewDishes.setListAdapter that needs to be called, but it throws another error: `Non static method cannot be referenced from a static content`

Any pointers as to how I can get past this error, please?

Comment: So you want to display json data onto listview ?

Comment: Can you post your java file?

Comment: @Apoorv the java file is mentioned in the description. [ http://pastebin.com/8UEgcyfa ]

Comment: @ZubairAhmadKhan I want to display the parsed menu items, not the exact json, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_viewdishes, R.id.label, adobe_products));
```

by

```
ViewDishes.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_viewdishes, R.id.label, adobe_products));
```

`setListAdapter` is a method of `ListFragment` and not `Asynctask` so you need to use `ViewDishes.this` instead of `this` in `onPostExecute`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. the code compiles successfully. upon executing in the emulator, the app exits. here's the logcat output: http://pastebin.com/pUgr8QWU

Comment: Also, i tried googling this error, and it was mentioned almost everywhere that i should have a `android:id="@id/android:list"` , but it was correctly so before.

Answer (score 0):

First : change to **`ViewDishes.this.setListAdapter(....)`**

Second : You cannot use a custom view with the default ArrayAdapter. You are passing `R.layout.fragment_viewdishes` to the ArrayAdapter. But this layout is your custom view and the default ArrayAdapter doesn't know about it. So, either pass a default list item layout (like **`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`** ) or create your CustomArrayAdapter and override the getView() method to inflate your custom layout.

Comment: i'm getting a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'` after i applied your suggestion.
i am guessing that this error is because the list needs to displayed in a fragment view. Can that be a reason?

Comment: That is because ListFragment expects the id to be that. You could either change the id in the layout of setContentView. Or use a normal Fragment and use your own listView in it